# Remote server is ping-able but unreachable via TCP/UDP - how to debug?

Tags: debian, performance, connection, timeout

I'm running a Debian Jessie server hosted by a company (so I only get to access it remotely) with several LXC based virtual machines running on it which in turn run several services from XMPP to IMAP, SMTP and IRC. Sometimes, maybe twice per week, I observe the following effect: the server (the host and all the guests) becomes unresponsive for any TCP or UDP based services I'm running. I can still ping it but packets do not make it for 2 minutes at a time up to an hour for any TCP/UDP based services. Sometimes, the connection becomes rather shaky with the server being reachable in 2-3 minute intervals with small windows where I can establish a connection.

I logged system stats like hard drive usage, CPU usage and memory usage over time and there is nothing out of the ordinary. CPU usage is generally under 20% and swap is never used.

I would like to make my datacenter responsible for the problem but the server is ping-able the whole time, so I doubt that the problem is in the route toward my server.

Since this problem occurs rather seldom, I would not like to take all my LXC services offline to see whether the problem is maybe connected to one of them. Instead, I'd like to be able to run some more diagnostics during the times that I observe this issue.

Which other tools can I use to debug this problem?

Comment: When you say the server does not respond, do you mean the host or the guests?

Comment: @mzhaase: I mean both. I clarified this in the text now. Thanks!

Comment: I had a similar issue with a web server in that case i ran a test every 10 seconds which essentially tested the web connection with curl like:
`curl -sL -w "%{http_code}\\n" "http://www.example.com/" -o /dev/null` with that data showing 200's then 000's i was able to point at the issue being their networking.

Comment: @josch how is the routing done? NAT? If both the host and the guest are having problems it must be something with the host rounting that is going wrong.

Comment: @cormpadre: How does that make sure that it's their networking? It could also mean that something on my server is faulty. This command shows me the symptom but not the cause.

Comment: @mzhaase: Which routing? The routing from my host to the virtual hosts? How can this affect whether or not I reach my host from the outside? Also, if there is a routing problem, why does it happen in these intervals? I would expect that if something is misconfigured then it's a permanent problem.

Comment: if you can run this on both the host and request the host you can eliminate the possibility that the host or internal host routing is at fault. It is definately not proof of any kind but would be a solid place to start from.